# Cannot Find Docker Host Certificate Authentication Credentials

Tags: docker, jenkins, docker-swarm

I'm currently running Jenkins lts in docker and i wanted to try the Docker Swarm Plugin. However is can't seem to find the Docker Host Certificate Authentication Credentials anywhere when adding a cloud provider. See Image:[Credentials](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kSM4R.png)

Is it a plugin that i need to install? 
My current docker plugins: 
docker-commons  1.16

docker-java-api 3.0.14

docker-plugin   1.1.9

docker-swarm    1.8

docker-workflow 1.21

I'm at a complete loss, help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described in the changelogs of docker-commons plugin, "Docker Host Certificate Authentication Credentials" was renamed to "X.509 Client Certificate" since 1.16.

Link : https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker-commons-plugin/releases/tag/docker-commons-1.16